# using GraphFames on java maven project

Tags: java, graphframes

I'd like to use GraphFrames with java in my maven project.

in the official documentation they said that APIs are provided for scala, python and JAVA:
https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html

but in real I find only APIs for scala and python!

so my question is: can I realy use  GraphFrames with java ?

Comment: Question more like to the contributor, you can ask this question at their github repo.

Comment: you are right! and this is what I have done!

Comment: It seems that we only have this tutorial in the Internet. https://www.baeldung.com/spark-graph-graphframes